# Pandas - Alter week number based on the day of the week derived from the date column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe.

| Date | Week_Num | WeekDay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/23 | 1 | Sunday |
| 02/01/23 | 1 | Monday |
| 04/01/23 | 1 | Wednesday |
| 05/01/23 | 1 | Thursday |
| 07/01/23 | 1 | Saturday |

I understand that the third row is in the first week, however I want to use Wednesday as a cut off point as by this point half the week has passed so the following days should move to the next week, such as below.

| Date | Week_Num | WeekDay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/23 | 1 | Sunday |
| 02/01/23 | 1 | Monday |
| 04/01/23 | 1 | Wednesday |
| 05/01/23 | 2 | Thursday |
| 07/01/23 | 2 | Saturday |

My attempts so far have been sporadic in their success, this is also somewhat of a edge case but one set of data seems to be prone to these sort of oddities so I wanted a solution.

The idea I have in my head is to use something like:

```
if Weekday-Number > 3 then Week_Num + 1
else do nothing
```

I understand how to do each part separately, but bringing them together is where I get stuck.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the code to generate its own dates, week nums and weekdays or you are going to supply it with dates weeknums (all '1's) and weekdays and you want the code to update the week_num only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on this and have managed to create a method that allows for multiple years worth of data without it creating errors.

```
#Convert week numbers correctly
        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])   
        df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y')
        df_2018 = df[df['Year'].str.contains('2018')==True]
        df_2019 = df[df['Year'].str.contains('2019')==True]

##Date formatting - 2019
        df_2019 .Date = pd.to_datetime( df_2019 .Date, dayfirst=True )
        dayOfWeekMap = { 0: "Monday", 1: "Tuesday", 2: "Wednesday", 3: "Thursday", 4: "Friday",
                5: "Saturday", 6: "Sunday" }
        df_2019 ["WeekDay"] = df_2019 .Date.dt.dayofweek.map( dayOfWeekMap )
        start_date = pd.to_datetime( "29/12/2018", dayfirst=True ) 
        df_2019 ["Week_Number"] = ( ( df_2019 .Date - start_date ).dt.days // 7 ).astype( int ) + 1

##Date formatting - 2018
        df_2018 .Date = pd.to_datetime( df_2018 .Date, dayfirst=True )
        dayOfWeekMap = { 0: "Monday", 1: "Tuesday", 2: "Wednesday", 3: "Thursday", 4: "Friday",
                5: "Saturday", 6: "Sunday" }
        df_2018 ["WeekDay"] = df_2018 .Date.dt.dayofweek.map( dayOfWeekMap )
        start_date = pd.to_datetime( "01/01/2018", dayfirst=True ) 
        df_2018 ["Week_Number"] = ( ( df_2018 .Date - start_date ).dt.days // 7 ).astype( int ) + 1
```

This has now created 2 separate df for each year with their start dates being shifted slightly to keep them aligned. After this I will concat them together and then take care of any week 53 numbers that have appeared.

```
#Concat and week 53 fix
        frames = [df_2018,df_2019]
        df_combo = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)
        
        df_combo ['Year'] = df_combo ['Year'].astype('int')
        df_combo .loc[df_combo ["Week_Number"] == 53, "Year"] += 1 
        df_combo .loc[df_combo ["Week_Number"] == 53, "Week_Number"] -= 52
```

This may still have to efficiency improvements to be made but for the size of the dataset will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

"Shortly" (one-liner), you can use `cumsum()`:

```py
df['Week_Num'] = df['WeekDay'].eq('Wednesday').cumsum().add(1).shift(1).fillna(1).astype(int)
```

---

Example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'Date': ['01/01/23', '02/01/23', '04/01/23', '05/01/23', '07/01/23', '07/01/23', '07/01/23', '07/01/23', '07/01/23', '07/01/23'],
    'WeekDay': ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday']
})
```

Outputs:

```
       Date    WeekDay  Week_Num
0  01/01/23     Sunday         1
1  02/01/23     Monday         1
2  04/01/23  Wednesday         1
3  05/01/23   Thursday         2
4  07/01/23   Saturday         2
5  07/01/23  Wednesday         2
6  07/01/23   Thursday         3
7  07/01/23   Saturday         3
8  07/01/23  Wednesday         3
9  07/01/23   Thursday         4
```

---

#### Explanations:

1. We introduce a new column `Week_Num` to `df`
2. We use `cumsum()` which accumulates a value when we meet a specific requirement notated by `.eq`
3. The `.eq` part is if we meet a WeekDay 'Wednesday'
4. We add one to each row because `cumsum` starts from 0 and we want to start from 1.
5. We shift downwards each row in the dataframe by 1 to change only the rows not including 'Wednesday'
6. Because we shifted each row downwards then the first row will have `NaN` - so we fill it with the week_num of `1`
7. We convert the row to have integer values with the `astype(int)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas [Timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html#:%7E:text=Represents%20a%20duration%2C%20the%20difference,with%20it%20in%20most%20cases.) objects.

Using just your `Date` column, you can convert it to a pandas [datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) object (and in fact use it to create your `WeekDay` column).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame( 
    data = {"Date":["1/1/23", "2/1/23", "4/1/23", "5/1/23", "7/1/23" ]}
)
>>> df.Date = pd.to_datetime( df.Date, dayfirst=True )
>>> df

    Date
0   2023-01-02
1   2023-01-03
2   2023-01-04
3   2023-01-05
```

Create the `WeekDay` column:

```
>>> dayOfWeekMap = { 0: "Monday", 1: "Tuesday", 2: "Wednesday", 3: "Thursday", 4: "Friday",
                5: "Saturday", 6: "Sunday" }
>>> df["WeekDay"] = df.Date.dt.dayofweek.map( dayOfWeekMap )
>>> df

    Date    WeekDay
0   2023-01-01  Sunday
1   2023-01-02  Monday
2   2023-01-04  Wednesday
3   2023-01-05  Thursday
4   2023-01-07  Saturday
```

Finally, get the week number with your custom cutoff. First, define the day you want to start. For your test data, I would start at Wednesday 28/12/2023 so that 3/1/2023 is has `Week_Num = 1`, but 4/1/2023 has `Week_Num = 2`.

```
>>> start_date = pd.to_datetime( "28/12/2022", dayfirst=True )
>>> df["Week_Num"] = ( ( df.Date - start_date ).dt.days // 7 ).astype( int ) + 1
>>> df

    Date        WeekDay Week_Num
0   2023-01-01  Sunday      1
1   2023-01-02  Monday      1
2   2023-01-04  Wednesday   2
3   2023-01-05  Thursday    2
4   2023-01-07  Saturday    2
```

What's happening here: We take the difference in the number of days from the date in the observation from the start date, floor division by 7 (so 6 days after start date is 0, 7 days from start date is 1, 8 days from start date is 1), and then add 1 so that our counter starts at 1.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple, non-iterative solution using the current data frame. If the WeekDay column was expressed as a number rather than text, a simple df.loc[] statement would give you the desired result.

```
df.loc[df["WeekDay"] > 4, "Week_Num"] += 1
```

This is saying to locate the rows where the Weekday > 4 and increment the Week_Num value by 1.

Using the data frame you have posted, a slower, iterative solution (not recommended) can be used along with the weekday() function from the datetime library.

```
#loop through each data frame row
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    #if the date is past wednesday, increment week_num
    if(row["dates"].weekday() > 4):
        df.at[i, "week_num"] += 1
```

The code iterates through each row item and increments the Week_Num based on an if statement. Using this method also means the WeekDay column is obsolete since datetime allows you to get the weekday number from the date.